# my Junit tests passed but the code coverage for JUnit test methods didn't pass

Tags: java, junit

How could I fix this issue? I would like to reach 100% test coverage for my `DonorTest` class but it seems like there are issues with `try/catch`.

[image]

Here is the methods that i wanted to test.

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't be looking for coverage of your *tests* - you should be looking for coverage of the *production* code. You don't *expect* those method calls to complete without an exception, so they're not going to be fully covered.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I have 100% coverage for my production code so I guess I'm good.

Comment: I think you can tell it to exclude the test folder from code coverage.